# Catch accept event when calling number using twilio javascript client

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I want to catch the accept event when calling a number using the twilio client javascript.
The 'connection' event of the device is fired as I want for incoming calls.
But the connection event for outgoing calls(created by call function) is fired immediately after created.
I want to show if the receiver has accepted a call or not.

-- Server code --

```
const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse()

twiml
  .dial({
    answerOnBridge: true,
    callerId: phoneNumber.number,
    record: 'record-from-answer',
  })
  .number(
    {
      statusCallback: apiUrl(
        `twilio-client/callback?smsContactId=${smsContact.id}&agentId=${agent.id}`
      ),
    },
    lead.phone
  )
```

-- Client code --

```
this.device = new Twilio.Device(token, {
    codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
    fakeLocalDTMF: true,
    enableIceRestart: true,
    enableRingingState: true,
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe this is the default behaviour, but you can change that by setting the `enableRingingState` flag when you setup the device.

With that flag, the connection will start by emitting [a `ringing` event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#onringing-handlerhasearlymedia). Then, when the call connection changes to "open" it will fire [the `accept` event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#accept-handler).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use that flag now. Accept event is fired when ringing starts. I need to know when receiver accepts a call. Is it impossible?

Comment: Oh, I think you need to set [`answerOnBridge="true"` in your `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#answeronbridge) in your TwiML too for this to work. Let me know if that helps and I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: It was set too :(. Maybe no solution?

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me the TwiML you are using?

Comment: I updated the question, please let me know if it's not enough

Comment: That really should work... As one last fallback, you can enable the ringing and connected events for your statusCallback and send them to your client side over a websocket.

Comment: Ok, let me try again

Comment: @ahadortiz did you figure this out? Not working for me either even after following instructions in twilio docs [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/connection#onringing-handlerhasearlymedia)